# Does "shatter" in "Shatterdome" really refer to storms?

Tags: word-meaning, translation

When I watched Polish premiere of movie *Pacific Rim* last year, word "Shatterdome" was translated to mean either "Dome of Storms" or "Dome of Thunders". This has been bugging me ever since. I have browsed several online English dictionaries and couldn't find any definition that would link word "shatter" to thunderstorms.

Now, when it comes to English-to-Polish movie translations, I have seen both ones that are absolutely brilliant and ones that have glaring rookie mistakes. Therefore, my question is: is that a correct translation and I'm missing some etymological context, or did translator see "_erdome" and immediately thought of that one *Mad Max* movie?

Comment: We have in spanish (remember Del Toro speak spanish) the verb "astillar" for a meaning similar to "shatter", that is, to break - wood for instance - into small pieces. And the noun "astillero" with the meaning "shipyard", the place where ships are built. In the origin of the word, wooden ships, now steel ones also.
So for me (without other additional hint) 'shatterdome' is the same as the spanish 'astillero', only one where jaeger are built instead of ships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We do speak of [lightning *shattering* the sky](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thunder%20shattered,lightning%20shattered,%20thunder%20shattering,%20lightning%20shattering&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cthunder%20shattered%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthunder%20shattered%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThunder%20shattered%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Clightning%20shattered%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blightning%20shattered%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLightning%20shattered%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthunder%20shattering%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clightning%20shattering%3B%2Cc0t4;,thunder%20shattered;,c0;,s0;;thunder%20shattered;,c0;;Thunder%20shattered;,c0;.t4;,lightning%20shattered;,c0;,s0;;lightning%20shattered;,c0;;Lightning%20shattered;,c0;.t1;,thunder%20shattering;,c0;.t1;,lightning%20shattering;,c0). We also talk about ear-shattering (loud) thunder and so on. Having said that, the word "Shatterdome" in English is pretty meaningless itself (domes are inert and do not *shatter* things [transitively], and a dome which itself [intransitively] is full of cracks and crazes would be called a *shatter**ed*** dome). So I'm not sure if there could be a good, "meaning preserving", translation: what meaning is there to preserve? I'd argue that's a general problem for translating (meaningless) names. *– Dan Bron Sep 26 '15 at 12:19*

Answer (score 0):

It refers to this place being the shattered remains of the force of jaegers. The pieces of a resistance that miss Mori could restore. It might be better to translate it as "dome of pieces".

Comment: In general, please provide evidence to support your answers. - [From Review](http://ell.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/45058)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I'd appreciate if you clarified whether that is official intent behind the name or your personal interpretation. (Also both of you having "Max" as the username confused me for a moment.)